# Including a remote php file as a resource

Tags: php, resources, include

I am trying to include remote php files as a resource but I am having a bit of trouble. I went into the `php.ini` files and set `allow_url_fopen` to `ON`. I also looked for the setting `allow_url_include` but it was not in the file, I added it to the php.ini file and also set that to on.

If I try to include using

```
 include ('http://somewebsite.com/lib/somescript.php');
```

The server / php spits out a message saying:

> URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration

I also get a message saying:

> failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in blah blah blah

The seconed way I am trying to acomplish the same result is using fopen but I am just getting the content of the file, thats not what I need I need my local script to see the remote script as an executabel rescource.

```
$myscript = fopen("http://someotherwebsite/lib/my_script.php", "r");
$incmyscript= fread($myscript , 9999);
fclose($myscript);
// include in the contents of my_script.php    
echo $incmyscript;
```

I have to be doing something wrong? I know echoing out the variabel $incmyscript is wrong, but I can't think of a way to place in the code. I am not sure if fopen is the best best way to get what I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please include the relavent lines in the php.ini .... maybe set incorrectly ?

Comment: allow_url_fopen = onallow_url_include = on

Answer (score 2):

The message you are getting:

```
URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration
```

Indicates that the `allow_url_include` setting in your php.ini is set to Off. Enabling that option will allow you to do remote file inclusion, but be very careful with this as it's a pretty big security risk once the other site would be compromised (A hacker could easily inject their own remote code to your site).

Comment: This is also a security hole if the attack can place a man-in-the-middle attack (as no transport security is used).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `echo`, you could use [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

**Only do this if you want to execute PHP code from the other server, not if you just want to include HTML!**

Even if you *really* want to execute PHP code from the other server, a man-in-the-middle could execute arbitrary PHP code on your server. You should therefore better use HTTPS or avoid the inclusion of the remote file at all.

Example:

```
$myscript = fopen("https://someotherwebsite/lib/my_script.php", "r");
$incmyscript= fread($myscript , 9999);
fclose($myscript);
$incmyscript);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the echo you could use this:

```
eval($incmyscript);
```

But be careful, this is very bad practice!
READ THIS: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: I would *never* recommend using `eval` on a cross-site request. **ever**.

Answer (score 0):

If you can trust remote script then you can call [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

```
eval ($incmyscript);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If `http://somewebsite.com/lib/somescript.php` served by server supporting PHP you're trying to include it's output, not the code itself! Otherwise it's a just wrong and may be considered as security hole!
2. What you're trying to do is opening of a major security hole!

Comment: It's not a security hole if you trust the other side (actually it is, because no transport security is use).

Comment: You can trust the other side until it got hacked/broken/angry on you, than you're in bad place... You not only trust it, you rely on it, from this point.

Comment: Who tells you that `somewebsite.com` is not run by the same webmaster?

Comment: @user1132323: Well, see my answer then. It's still a security problem to use eval if you use unencrypted HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

If the remote server is configured to process .php files, you won't be able to get the source for it. The server will process the PHP and then return any output. If getting remote PHP sources were possible, hackers would be grabbing our code and looking for vulnerabilities way too easily!

Comment: You should also write your code so that a cracker that has access to your code could not exploit it.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I am going to convince my boss to go a different route.