# Including remote files in PHP

Tags: php, include

I am unable to include a remote PHP file in my PHP script.
here is what I did:

1. Set `allow_url_include` to `on` on php.ini.
2. Add the following to the top of my index

   ```
   $content = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/folder/file.php');
   ```

but still cannot use any function inside file.php which is in the remote server.
the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function makeConnection()
```

**Note:** makeConnection() is inside file.php

Comment: Did you restart apache after editing allow_url_include ? Did you set allow_url_fopen to on ? Moreover tp include a file , use include and not file_get_contents

Comment: flagged for duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744156/including-a-remote-php-file-as-a-resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that the function '`makeConnection()`' is declared in the external file.php then you won't see the function because the external server is parsing the php code **NOT** sending you the raw code.

You'll need to save the external `file.php` to something like `file.txt` so that the server returns the contents without processing.

Try it and see if it works for you.

If it does then you can plan something more efficient.

Comment: It works! Many Thanks. May I change the file extension to .anything so that no one can access it?

Comment: Yes, anything you like.

Answer (score 2):

file_get_contents and include are not the same, file_get_contents just gets the file contents (like it's own name says), include executes the code which is in the file...
So do you just want to get file contents or execute code from remote server?

if you want to include it's just

```
include('http://domain.com/folder/file.php');
```

Comment: The function will still be hidden because file.php gets run on the server.

Comment: arf yes... he can try to get it by `ftp://user:pass@domain.com/dir/file.php`

Comment: FTP usernames and passwords? A solution but naughty.

Comment: yes... but file.txt may be a problem : if someone call the url he will se php code, and may see security vulnerabilities, or db structure etc...

Comment: I did mention that a better plan is required. An exposed file.txt is better than ftp username and password revealed. Surely you must agree.

Comment: yes sure of course i agree that's why i gave you a plus, and anyway including à distant file is totaly insecure, no matter the way you to this, if the distant server is hacked, you get hacked...

Answer (score -1):

Use [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function after you download the code:

```
<?
$content = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/folder/file.php'); 
eval($content)
?>
```

But be careful with including something from other source without checking.

Comment: direct from manual **The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.**